# "10 $digest() iterations reached" при фильтрации

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Код фильтрации через директиву `ng-reapet`:

```
var taskApp = angular.module('task', []);

<div class="item-block-lio" ng-repeat="todo in tasks | orderBy:predicate:reverse | sortField:status track by $index" ng-cloak> 

//сам фильтр, который вызывает ошибку
taskApp.filter('sortField', function (){
    var filtered = [];
    return function(items, status) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (items[i].status == status) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

В итоге появляется ошибка: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Код который возвращает массив объектов

```
$scope.get_tasks = function(){
    $http.post('/Task/default/index', {type:$scope.model.type}).success(function(data) {
         //DataCache.put('tasks', data);
      //  $scope.tasks = data;
        angular.forEach(data, function(task){
               task.cost = Number(task.cost);
               task.second = Number(task.second);
                task.status = Number(task.status);
               $scope.tasks.push(task);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> taskApp.filter('sortField', function (){
>   var filtered = [];
>   return function(items, status) {
> ```

У тебя по сути глобальный массив получился. Каждый вызов фильтра добавляет элементы в этот массив. Перенеси объявление массива для результата внутрь фильтрующей функции.

---

> ```
> track by $index
> ```

Это не надо для объектов.

Comment: Когда убираю то вообще появляется ошибка `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys`  и еще в придачу ошибка `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: @modelfak, сделай пример на jsfiddle или в вопросе в виде сниппета.

Comment: @modelfak, хотя нет, не надо. Я понял, в чём косяк.

Comment: ок, пока добавил код еще который возвращает массив

Comment: @modelfak, обновил ответ. А код http-запроса в этом вопросе бесполезен.

Comment: Спасибо ))) за помощь!